# Set robot dimensions

Tags: ubuntu, ros, mobile-robot-toolkit

I'm using MRPT, in particular the CHolonomicVFF class, for a university project. I made a ROS node which implements a simple obstacle avoidance functionality, it seems to work but I need a way to specify the robot dimensions. I checked the CHolonomicVFF class wiki, but i didn't find anything helpful.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`mrpt::nav::CHolonomicVFF`](http://mrpt.ual.es/reference/devel/classmrpt_1_1nav_1_1_c_holonomic_v_f_f.html) (and all other "holonomic" solvers in `mrpt-nav`) works on the assumption of a "point robot", without radius.

In other words, you should *enlarge* all your obstacles with the robot radius before feeding them to this class. Similar to the way [cost_map](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d) does in ROS.

The reason for this design is that "holonomic" navigators in MRPT play a role in the navigation pipeline **after** what is called PTG-based transformations, which abstract away the actual robot shape so it can be dealt as a "point".